# Google Play services out of date.

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm working on an Android app, that targets Android API versions : `17 --> 23`, I extensively use the google play services for 2 core features :

1. GeoLoc : with FusedLocationApi
2. Google maps.

Now, I'm using the google play services version `8.1`, it works fine on all the devices except ones with Android 4.2 (API 17) displaying me the message : `Google Play services out of date. Requires 7571000 but found 1015`

Is there any specific google play services version I could downgrade to, to be able to use the FusedLocation + Google maps (with basic callbacks) for all Android versions from API 17 to 23.

Thank you.

Comment: You tried api 17 with a real device or emulator?

Comment: @Fondesa : Thanks. 17 with a real device.

Comment: @Fondesa : is this something common on Emulators with API 17 ?

Comment: You can try to download the google play services apk here: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/ and do the update yourself. It should be work.